# How can I make a nested scrollable container in a flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox and inside nested several `divs`. In a deeper level is the main content (in yellow). I'd like to make it scrollable horizontally, but it only works if the `divs` between `.flexbox` and `.content` aren't there. So if the divs are there, `overflow-x: scroll` on the `.content` doesn't behave as I'd expect.

Can anyone explain that? What would a possible solution look like to create a nested scrollable container in a flexbox?

```css
.flexbox {
 display: flex;
}

.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
 <div> <!-- multiple nested divs like this one -->
   <div class="content"> <!-- finally content -->
      <p> I want to be able to scroll in here. </p>
      <p> Not in the whole page </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/jwabKG

Comment: give me a second to think about it, because the real example is a bit more complicated and not sure if I know the max-width, thanks for the comment!

Comment: min-width: 0 might be the winner

Comment: yeah that's the best way to do it. submitted an answer with why that's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox/#flex-common

> By default, flex items won’t shrink below their minimum content size (the length of the longest word or fixed-size element). To change this, set the min-width or min-height property.

You can use `min-width: 0` or `max-width: 100%` on `.flexbox > div`.

```css
.flexbox {
 display: flex;
}

.flexbox > div {
  min-width: 0;
}

.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
 <div> <!-- multiple nested divs like this one -->
   <div class="content"> <!-- finally content -->
      <p> I want to be able to scroll in here. </p>
      <p> Not in the whole page </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```css
.flexbox {
 display: flex;
}

.flexbox > div {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
 <div> <!-- multiple nested divs like this one -->
   <div class="content"> <!-- finally content -->
      <p> I want to be able to scroll in here. </p>
      <p> Not in the whole page </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your inner `<div>` elements are exceeding the width of the screen. I'd recommend setting a `max-width: 100%` on all `<div>` elements that come directly under the flexbox, so that they don't escape the bounds. This still allows you to keep the `display: flex` parent.

```css
.flexbox {
 display: flex;
}

.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.flexbox > div {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
 <div> <!-- multiple nested divs like this one -->
   <div class="content"> <!-- finally content -->
      <p> I want to be able to scroll in here. </p>
      <p> Not in the whole page </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
      <p> foo bar content </p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)